# How to find lines of contact with shapes

Tags: javascript, canvas

I need to find contact lines with shapes.
I need to find red lines, start and end points.
[image]

I found this option on the site https://www.redblobgames.com/articles/visibility/, calculate the rays, but it seems to me that this option is not the best.

While I did not find anything, are there any options how to do this?)

Comment: I think it can be solved by assuming that you got two circles, because for them you can draw a line between the two centers of the circle, and move it orthogonally by the radius, then generalize it to two curcles with different sizes

Comment: How are the shapes defined?